# Is there a significant performance difference when declaring types in type script?

Tags: performance, typescript

This question is rather generally about the best practive in typescript. I currently declare all my variables with types. I just wonder, if there would be a significant difference when leaving the types.

If not, I am curious why there is an option to declare types at all (beside readability).

Comment: Before asking any question... please see already existing typescript related questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance difference at all.

The types are removed from the code during compilation. They are not present at run time.